Best way to embed Nextjs app in another website
I have a Nextjs app using app-directory and server-side rendering, I have been asked to create a white-label version for third parties to host on their websites, the simplest way is to use Iframe but it does not work properly due to router issues, and redirects do not work. the database is already configured for multiple organizations but I am not sure how to let the app know which organization is requesting the data. the ideal solution I am looking for is to host Nextjs on Vercel or Netlify, embed it somehow in another website, and let the app detect the organization based on the hostname

To identify the organization you can use the getServerSideProps and get the hostname from the URL and then pass it to the NexJs.app:  req.headers.host

Are you able to host the entire app on your domain and place the customers version on a subdomain of that? The customer could create a cname record if they want a custom host name. Seems better than an iframe.

iframe will you layout issues especially when you have responsive pages. Plus security issues will also be there. you need to work on it a case by case basis depending on the stack of each customer. e.g. one customer is having a HA setup of their website which is geo redundant, they would want something similar then. NextJS can be hosted in containerized environment and that is your best bet to ask for kubernetes instance and push you nodejs app there for each customer.

There are multiple ways such as Iframe, React App, 'SDK. Based on your requirement you can use these ways. Let's say simplest way it Iframe but React App will provide you more feature and flexibility. and 'SDK will be better than above both. all these have there own pros and cons.

iFrame is still the way to go.
Just make sure it uses first-party cookies and you know how to do Cname masking for that on the domain you're sitting
